# How to make opentype font in luatex latex work with unicode combining diacritical marks

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, typography, opentype

We use s with caron
COMBINING CARON
U+030C

but also s with curved breve (curving up)
COMBINING BREVE
U+0306

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic

in a book we are typesetting with luatex using an adobe Berkeley opentype font on a mac

We tried

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Berkeley}
\newcommand\cdmbreve{\symbol{"0306}}
\begin{document}
s\cdmbreve

\end{document}
```

but it just outputs a plain s with no accent and no error.

It seems unicode suggests combining diacritical marks as the best way to add accents to a character.

What is the best way to implement this with this opentype font and luatex?  Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: add `\tracinglostchars=3 ` to your preamble then compile. If you get an error your font doesn't have the accent and you will have to use another font or find a way to fake it.

Comment: your log will (preumably) show a missing character warning not an error unless you set `\tracinglostchars` to 3 as Ulrike suggests, you can also use the standard latex markup `\u{s}` which may be easier to adjust to get the breve from another font (I do not have this font to test)

Comment: Thank you both.  Sadly \tracinglostchars=3 or 2 does not bring up an error for me in luatex.   Standard markup \u{s} also produces no accent.

Comment: @DavidB That sounds like the font contains the combining characters but the glyphs are empty which seems weird. Of course it's hard to determine exactly what's going on without seeing the font.

Answer (score 0):

```
\newcommand\Sbreve{\accent\string"02D8 S}%  unicode U+02D8 for breve glyph
```

worked great for all characters where the accent goes above the main letter such as S.

The caron, breve, diaresis etc. were all in this Berkeley font at their correct unicode hex address.

The TeX \accent command places the accent above so did not work for accents such as slash or cedilla that do not appear above the character.

You could place these with low level TeX commands as explained in other questions.

Comment: You lose all the kerning by using the `\accent` primitive.